# How to avoid repetition of "due to"

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, colons, parallelism, repetition

I want to say that something has happened due to several reasons. So I used word ***due to*** to say the reason but *due to* comes respectively. I avoided it in my 2nd sentence. Would it be ok?

> Missing of object relationships can be found *due to* missing of a
>   classified object, *due to* incomplete boundary estimation or *due to* an
>   obstacle between two objects.
>
> Missing of object relationship can be found *due to*: missing of a
>   classified object, incomplete boundary estimation or obstacle between
>   two objects.

this  might be confused for others... other than content I am actually looking for the correct sentence pattern.

Comment: yes you are right. but it is only one sentence of the whole text. so that others might misguide.

Comment: I'm going to say this is Not A Real Question. @niro - you have many more problems in this text besides the repetition of "due to". It's really just proof-reading, which could probably be better addressed in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: There is no need to avoid a single repetition of "due to".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence has some bigger problems than repetition of "due to", as FumbleFingers says. Here's how I think you should rewrite it:

> Some object relationships are missing because a classified object is missing, a boundary estimation is incomplete, or an obstacle exists between two objects.

Another possibility is this:

> Some object relationships are missing because there is a missing classified object, an incomplete boundary estimation, or an obstacle between two objects.

Another possibility is this:

> Some object relationships are missing because a classified object is missing, a boundary estimation is incomplete, or an obstacle is between two objects.

Another possibility is this:

> Some object relationships are missing because of a missing classified object, an incomplete boundary estimation, or an obstacle between two objects.

You can always substitute "because of" for "due to", or change the syntax slightly to eliminate the "of" in "because of".

You can also say something like this:

> Some object relationships are missing for one (or more) of three reasons: a missing classified object, an incomplete boundary estimation, or an obstacle between two objects.

There are usually many ways to express an idea. The best way is surely the clearest, hopefully the briefest, and usually structurally parallel.

Comment: many many thanks for the constructive way that you showed me. thanks

Comment: Good one @Bill Franke. I wish more programmers remembered the perl computer language and Unix inspired saying "There's more than one way to do it" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it Both in language and in much more restricted than perl computer languages, there's always opportunity to re-shape on a macro scale, instead of tinkering at the edges when things aren't right.

Comment: @Chris Or as we say in the literary biz, "Don't patch it, pitch it."